# Change the shipping method name in backend

Tags: php, magento

I have changed many shipping methods and its display on the front end. Because of the customization, I have given names programmatically like "Standard: 1-2 business days:2" Now I want to change the display in back end and the display of the methods like the above to "Standard (1-2 business days)". I want to know where to change these names when saving into db.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the translation of the shipping methods in Mage_Shipping.csv located in app/locale/en_US/Mage_Shipping.csv

Search for the line containing the name of your shipping method.
For example
    `"Flat Rate","Flat Rate"`
And change the last quote to what ever you want.
    `"Flat Rate","Shipping (1-2 days)"`